# How is it possible that the length of this string is increasing?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * odd(const char * S, char * dest);

int main()
{
    char * source = "abcdefghijklmnopacegiacegi";
    unsigned int length = strlen(source);
    char dest[length];
    printf("%s\n",odd(source, dest));
}

char * odd(const char * source, char * dest)
{
    int count = 0;
    unsigned int length = strlen(source);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if( (source[i] %2 )!= 0)
        {
            dest[count] = source[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

the size of dest increases and produces garbage for any values after the length of source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manually include the ending `\0` to the string, that is, at the end of `add`, you have to add:

```
dest[count] = '\0';
```

You know, the length of strings in C is accounted searching for the `\0` character. You have to include one of those at the end of each C string. If not, the string may contain any garbage till the first `\0` that will be printed.

Finally, when creating `dest`, you have also to increase the length of the reserved space in one to accomodate that ending 0 character. The `strlen` does not count that ending 0 character.

Answer (score 2):

Your `odd` function forgets to NUL-terminate `dest`, so `printf` continues to read happily past the intended end of the string, outputting the garbage that happens to be on the stack.

Also, `dest` must be one character longer, since `strlen` tells the length of the string *not including* the closing NUL, thus, if `source` is by chance all of odd characters, you have a (small) buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't copy the terminating `\0`.